# Add Referrer info to WooCommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I tried to add order tracking and I currently have this code:

```html
// Set cookie for new users
add_action( 'init', 'set_newuser_cookie'); // Run when WordPress loads
function set_newuser_cookie() {
    
    $cookie_value = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; // Get URL the user came to your site for
    
    if ( !is_admin() && !isset($_COOKIE['origin'])) { // If not an admin or if cookie doesn't exist already
        setcookie( 'origin', $cookie_value, time()+3600*24*30, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false); // Set cookie for 30 days
    }
}


// Check cookie when order made and add to order
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'add_referral_meta'); // Run when an order is made in WooCommerce

function add_referral_meta( $order_id, $posted ){
    $ref_url = $_COOKIE['origin']; // Get the cookie
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'referrer', $ref_url ); // Add to order meta
}
```

However, it doesn't work for me.
I can't see where the users who place orders are redirected from. And that's what I need to track campaigns.
I will be grateful if you tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use *woocommerce_new_order* hook instead? In this case, your code should look like this:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'add_referral_meta', 10, 1);
function add_referral_meta( $order_id ){
    $ref_url = $_COOKIE['origin']; // Get the cookie
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'referrer', $ref_url ); // Add to order meta
}
```

Comment: Thanks Artemy Kaydash,
This works extremely well for me.

Comment: How do you then see this data in the backend?